Logging in multithreaded actix-web application in rust
How can I log in different threads to main stdout in rust actix-web app. I spawn two workers (main function is initialized with #[tokio::main]):
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(actix_bot.clone()))
            .service(
                web::scope("/api").configure(router::router::request_handler),
            )
    })
    .workers(2)
    .bind((host, port))?
    .run()
    .await

But if I log something in handler, I cant see anything in stout console.
What is the easiest way to syncronize logging to one main stdout?
I use log and env_logger to write in stdout.
This is how I build logger in my main fun:
Builder::new().filter_level(LevelFilter::Info).init();

This is example of service config for actix-web:
pub fn request_handler(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(
        web::resource("/notification")
            .route(web::post().to(handle_notification)),
    )
    .service(
        web::resource("/pass-restore").route(web::post().to(pass_restore)),
    );
}

This is the example how I trying to log test log to console:
async fn handle_notification(
    req_body: String,
    actix_bot: web::Data<AppState>,
) -> impl Responder {
    info!("test log");

    // ...handler

I have no clue how to log with different threads. I'm newby in  Rust.

Logging works in multiple threads by default, you shouldn't need to do anything special. Please edit the question to include your env_logger setup. Also, does logging with the same setup work in a simple program that just logs something in main()?

I've just added the logger setup to the question description. And yes, simple logs work just fine; only logs that run in threads are not shown in the console. Thank you @user4815162342

And you're sure your handlers are actually running? For example, say you add info!("startup test") just after the builder initialization, and eprintln!("test test log") just after the info!("test log") call. Then you start and access your server - what gets printed?

@user4815162342 I receive this:
[2024-10-25T08:30:54Z INFO  fiat_payment_bot_rust] test log after logger initializing
test eprint log.
I getting info log, and then eprintln log.

Is the info!() in handle_notification the same import as the one at startup? I.e. both are just log::info, and not e.g. tracing::info or something else?

@user4815162342 I've just found that if i comment second .service chain with /restore-pass path in request_handler function - info() in handle_notification() function works as it should

I've used Rust logging in multi-threaded setups all the time, and it just work. Whatever is happening in your case I suspect has nothing to do with threads being used. If you want others to help you out, you'll need to create a minimal self-contained and runnable example that reproduces the issue. In any case, good luck!
